# How to register a module to ruby?

Tags: c#, ruby, object, module, ironruby

How do I register a module to ruby with IronRuby and C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean using IronRuby from C# or C# from IronRuby?

C# from IronRuby is easy(with some caveats)

```
require 'C:/.../my_awesome_class.dll'
MyAwesomeClass.do_something
```

calling IronRuby from C# is more complicated, and you probably want to look at the [docs for hosting ironruby](http://www.ironruby.net/Documentation/.NET/Hosting).

The [IronRuby .Net docs](http://www.ironruby.net/Documentation/.NET) are a good place to get started.